# Barplot no RStudio - 2 Colunas

Tags: r

estou tentando plotar os dados abaixo no R com o barplot mas deve estar errando em algo, vocês conseguem me ajudar?

```
dados_estado_civil <- "Estado_Civil   Set     Out
AMIGADO        2494   3857
CASADO         2500   3291
SEPARADO       2504   3545
SOLTEIRO       2504   2910"

dados_estado_civil <- read.table(textConnection(dados_estado_civil), header=TRUE)
head(dados_estado_civil)

  Estado_Civil   Set    Out
1      AMIGADO  2494   3857
2       CASADO  2500   3291
3     SEPARADO  2504   3545
4     SOLTEIRO  2504   2910
```

Queria plotar estes valores em um grafico de barras considerando os meses.

Comment: Valeu Marcus! Eu não conhecia o 'textConnection'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil de resolver isto é com o pacote `ggplot2`. Mas antes é preciso colocar os dados no chamado formato longo, usando a função `melt` do pacote `reshape2`:

```
library(reshape2)

dados_estado_civil <- melt(dados_estado_civil)
names(dados_estado_civil) <- c("Estado_Civil", "mes", "valor")
dados_estado_civil
      Estado_Civil mes valor
1      AMIGADO Set  2494
2       CASADO Set  2500
3     SEPARADO Set  2504
4     SOLTEIRO Set  2504
5      AMIGADO Out  3857
6       CASADO Out  3291
7     SEPARADO Out  3545
8     SOLTEIRO Out  2910
```

Veja que agora eu tenho uma coluna com valores repetidos para o estado civil, outra coluna com todos os meses e uma terceira coluna com todos os valores. Isto é importante porque o `ggplot2` entende os dados deste formato de maneira mais fácil. Eu posso, por exemplo, pintar as barras do meu gráfico de acordo com o estado civil:

```
library(ggplot2)    
ggplot(dados_estado_civil, aes(x=mes, y=valor, fill=Estado_Civil)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  labs(x="Mês", y="Quantidade", fill="Estado Civil")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OU, se eu achar que é melhor comparar a evolução de um mês para o outro dentro de cada estado civil, basta alterar a ordem de `x` e `fill`:

```
ggplot(dados_estado_civil, aes(x=Estado_Civil, y=valor, fill=mes)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  labs(x="Estado Civil", y="Quantidade", fill="Mês")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]